# label.isHidden = false does not appear, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

I have a UIView containing label and some other elements. At some point I need to toggle the visibility of the UIView, but I need other constraints to stay to keep the overall structure just without this UIView. I'm doing it with the height constraint of the UIView - make it 0. When toggling back, the UIView appears back (because other elements appear), but without the label. Label is not present at all.

```
if(vips.count == 0) {
        meetingVIPsLabel.isHidden = true
        meetingVipsHeight.constant = 0
        meetingVIPsLabel.text = ""
    } else {
        meetingVipsHeight.constant = 92
        meetingVIPsLabel.isHidden = false
        meetingVIPsLabel.text = MessagesInteractor.getMeetingVIPsMessage(with: vips.count)
    }
```

Before hiding the UIView ("Meeting 1 VIP" is what I need to appear):
[image]

After hiding the UIView and bringing it back:
[image]

Comment: Check that you are not changing `alpha`. Also check that the `text` you are setting is not actuall empty. Note you are changing `meetingVIPsLabel.text` when hiding and `hostedMeetingLabel.text` when showing.

Comment: sorry, inserted the other bit, that nevertheless had this error. Nice catch, but my issue is still there, I edited the post here with right snippet..

Comment: stop the app in debugger and print `text`, `alpha`, `frame`, `superview` and `hidden` for the label. Either the label got completely removed, or it is hidden, or empty.

Comment: all of these values seem to be fine, except the width after hiding and showing is a 0. But weirdly it is showing the text when I set a breakpoint.. it's inconsistent

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call layoutIfNeeded() to make sure the constraints take effect. After updating the constraints call

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: oh well, but then it crashes at this line... so not working

Comment: can you please share what crash says? This should be called if your are in ViewController class. If you are in some UIView class call self.layoutIfNeeded. Also make sure that you do it on main thread.

Comment: I am in the UIViewController, and the whole sequence of calls is in the DispatchQueue.main.async {...}

Comment: This line of code cannot cause crash. Can you read what is printed on the console to get to the cause of the crash.

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: but if I put it inside DispatchQueue.main.async {...} it doesn't crash, which is a bit strange - because it's already inside DispatchQueue.main.async {...} when I'm calling all three these methods

Comment: getMeetingVIPsMessage , is it also in main?